# Trying to get a modal to show up using html & javascript, but nothing shows up after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I followed a tutorial on how to do a simple modal and I am trying to get it to appear on my page after clicking on, but nothing happens.

The modal is styled in the css sheet as display:none.

html

```
<script src="modaltestjs.js"> </script>

</head>


    <body>
        <!--modal-->
        <div>
    <a href="#" id="button" class="button"> Click me </a>

        <div class="bg-modal"> 

            <div class="modal-content"> 

                <h4> Promotion/voucher code</h4> 
                <div class="close"> + </div>

            <form action="" method="POST"> 

                  <span> Promotion/voucher code: <input type="text" placeholder="Code"> </span>

               <button class="mbutton"> <a href=""> Ok </a> </button>
               <button class="mbutton"> <a href=""> Cancel </a> </button>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>


</body>
```

javascript

```
/*eslint-env browser*/

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    "use strict";
    document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = "flex";

});
```

css

```
/*modal styling*/
.bg-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: none;

}

.modal-content{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}


input:focus{

    background-color: lightgreen

}
```

I expected the modal box to appear but nothing happens once I click on "click me".

Comment: I would suggest that you add some console log lines to debug where your problem is. Print a liner to the console as the first thing you do when you click to see if the click even happens. Then print what the query returns to see what it finds.

Comment: @whxtn3y did you import the css file? The line `<script src="modaltestjs.js"> </script> ` import the javascript file so I think you didn't import the css file.

Comment: BTW the codes work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if I try it. (try to add document ready to see if your code is loading correctly)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
        "use strict";
        console.log("click")
        console.log(document.querySelector(".bg-modal"))
        document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = "flex";
      });
});
```

Also: try to add console.log and see if you get the click message in your console.